# How to insert homepage and current page in breadcrumbs?

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs

I'm working on breadcrumbs for a client's website, and I'm asking myself if homepage has to be in its code.

So, is it better to do :

**With link to homepage and current**

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Accueil</span>
    </a>
    >
</div> 
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Annonces</span>
    </a>
    > 
</div> 
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces/category" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Categorie</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces/category/produit" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Produit</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Without link to homepage and current page**

```
<a href="http://someclient.fr/" itemprop="url">Accueil</a> >
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Annonces</span>
    </a>
    > 
</div> 
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces/category" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">Category</span>
    </a>
</div>
<a href="http://someclient.fr/annonces/category/produit" itemprop="url">Produit</a>
```

You can try this codes with Google Structured Data Testing Tool (http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and you will see that homepage is not rendered with my first example.

So, what's the best solution ? How do you do for your sites ?

Thanks !

Comment: The homepage will not be in the breadcrumb links so you don't need to add it. The breadcrumb is the tree navigation so homepage is not required.

Comment: The breadcrumbs can be used in any way you want - doesn't have to be actual navigation. For example, if the visitor is 4 levels deep into a product screen you can have the breadcrumbs link to the most logical previous summary page for that product, not each step down in the path. The breadcrumb should help the visitor navigate to relevant content, not just track where they are. Also, google uses breadcrumbs in SERPs so make them categorical.

Answer (score 0):

For seo it's better without that links because you would have two links for the home page and  the other link is for the same page you are in...